# Spark Flatmap - what is the usage of evidence$4

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I happeneed to see the javadoc of flatmap function and come across "evidence$4" - what is the purpose of it.

```
public <U> RDD<U> flatMap(scala.Function1<T,scala.collection.TraversableOnce<U>> f,
                          scala.reflect.ClassTag<U> evidence$4)
```

I had used this flatmap function by passing a function but didn't use "evidence$4" anytime.